# AngularJS - Nested ng-repeat for table

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I just started with AngularJS and I'm trying to make a users table that shows the users for the application and the roles they are in (e.g. Admin, Editor, Anon) with checkboxes to take the users in and out of roles.

```
<tbody>
    <tr data-ng-repeat="item in pagedItems[currentPage] | orderBy:sortingOrder:reverse">
        <td class="table-item-title"><a title="{{item.UserName}}" href="" ng-click="loadEditForm(item.UserName)">{{item.UserName}}</a></td>
        <td class="hmax479">{{item.Email}}</td>
        <td align="center" data-ng-repeat="role in roles" style="align:center;">
             <input type="checkbox" data-ng-model="role.IsChecked" style="align:center;"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody
```

With the above code it updates the checkboxes for the entire group based on the last user that was clicked rather than for a single user. Is there any way I can change this code with something like a "user in users" ng-repeat to change this or do I need to add a new function in the controller?

Comment: Could you provide more code or a fiddle please?

Comment: `roles` is separate from `pagedItems`. Do you have a `item.roles=[]` to keep track of each user's roles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each user could have an array of `roles` to show the roles that has been assigned to the user. For each user, while looping through the roles, you use a `filter` to only check assigned roles. You could use a function in your controller to add/remove roles as the check boxes are selected/deselected.

```
<tbody>
  <tr data-ng-repeat="item in pagedItems[currentPage] | orderBy:sortingOrder:reverse">
    <td class="table-item-title"><a title="{{item.UserName}}" href="" ng-click="loadEditForm(item.UserName)">{{item.UserName}}</a></td>
    <td class="hmax479">{{item.Email}}</td>
    <td align="center" data-ng-repeat="role in roles" style="align:center;">
         <input type="checkbox" data-ng-checked="role | hasRole:item.Roles" data-ng-click="addOrRemove($parent.$index, role)" style="align:center;"/>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

The filter

```
app.filter('hasRole', function() {
    return function (role, userRoles) {
        var result = false;
        userRoles.forEach(function(value, index) { // loop through the roles
            // return true if the user has the role
            if(role.Name == value.Name) // This is replaced by any method of comparing roles 
               result = true;
        });
        return result;
    }
}
```

In your controller, you implement `addOrRemove()`